# Python - animation with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can one create animated diagrams using popular matplotlib library? I am particularly interested in animated gifs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The matplotlib docs provide an entire section of examples on [animation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/index.html) (see this [scipy](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Animations.html) tutorial also).  Most, however, involve using the various GUI widget backends.  There is one in there, "movie demo", that shows how to produce an avi of a series of PNGS.

To produce animated GIFs, I think your options are [pretty limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python).  Last I checked, [PIL didn't support them](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2005/12/06/python-imaging-library-pil-and-animated-gifs/).  You could however generate a series of PNGs using pyplot's savefig and then stitch them together using a call to ImageMagick or mencoder.

Answer (score 6):

### Update in 2017

Matplotlib has the *animation* module, and in it you find the `ImageMagickFileWriter` class. It is advertised as "File-based animated **gif** writer."

Documentation: http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.ImageMagickFileWriter.html#matplotlib.animation.ImageMagickFileWriter