# Plot multiple files

Tags: linux, simulation

I'd like to make an animation that illustrates the positions of some agents I'm simulating under Linux.
Basically, I have some files named file00001.dat, file00002.dat and so on.
I have to generate "something" that get files in order, and output an animated gif, a dynamic graph or whatever, that simulates the moving reading data from file.

I have control on the files, meaning that I can put identifiers or everything I want.

How would you achieve that? What programs would you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux, gnuplot is the old standby. And it can do [animated gif's as well](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00056000000000000000).

Answer (score 1):

There are many choices, but in general [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is a good one. It is a python library, so you have powerful libraries available to fine-tune or analyse your data set if you want to go beyond just quick plots. For very simple stuff you can always use the `pyplot` module from `matplotlib` that has many commands known from MATLAB or `gnuplot`.

For producing animations see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546780/python-animation-with-matplotlib-pyplot).

As an added plus its default outputs are much better than e.g. [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)'s or [plotutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/)'.