# python: Faster local maximum in 2-d matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

Given: R is an mxn float matrix

Output: O is an mxn matrix where O[i,j] = R[i,j] if (i,j) is a local max and O[i,j] = 0 otherwise. Local maximum is defined as the maximum element in a 3x3 block centered at i,j.

What's a faster way to do this operation on python using numpy and scipy.

```
m,n = R.shape
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        R[i,j]  *= (1 if R[min(0,i-1):max(m, i+2), min(0,j-1):max(n,j+2)].max() == R[i,j] else 0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html):

```
In [28]: from scipy.ndimage import maximum_filter
```

Here's a sample `R`:

```
In [29]: R
Out[29]: 
array([[3, 3, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 2, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 1, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 1]])
```

Get the maximum on 3x3 windows:

```
In [30]: mx = maximum_filter(R, size=3)

In [31]: mx
Out[31]: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 2, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Compare `mx` to `R`; this is a boolean matrix:

```
In [32]: mx == R
Out[32]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create `O`:

```
In [33]: O = np.where(mx == R, R, 0)

In [34]: O
Out[34]: 
array([[3, 3, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0]])
```