# Determine the coordinates of local maximas in a two-dimensional array using derivative

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, astropy

I have a `fits` image and I am trying to find the coordinates of *local maxima* in my image but so far I couldn't quite make it work. [My image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BBB3HWMYm2lTkVdTNzc2drTDhLcEE/view?usp=sharing) can be find here. 
What I have so far is

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.nimage as ndimage
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy import units as u
from astropy import coordinates as coord
from astropy.io import fits
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters
from scipy.ndimage.filters import maximum_filter
hdulist=fits.open("MapSNR.fits")
#reading a two dimensional array from fits file
d=hdulist[0].data
w=WCS("MapSNR.fits") 
idx,idy=np.where(d==np.max(d))
rr,dd=w.all_pix2word(idx,idy,o)
c=coord.SkyCoord(ra=rr*u.degree, dec=dd*u.degree)
#The sky coordinate of the image maximum
print c.ra
print c.dec
```

That is how I can find the global maximum of the image, but I would like to obtain the coordinates of the **local maximas** which have **the significance of being greater than three**.

What I have found by looking up in the web was [this following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111711/get-coordinates-of-local-maxima-in-2d-array-above-certain-value) which doesn't work properly in my case. 
**update**: I have used this function

```
def detect_peaks(data, threshold=1.5, neighborhood_size=5):

  data_max = filters.maximum_filter(data, neighborhood_size)
  maxima = (data == data_max)
  data_min = filters.minimum_filter(data, neighborhood_size)
  diff = ((data_max - data_min) > threshold)
  maxima[diff == 0] = 0 # sets values <= threshold as background
  labeled, num_objects = ndimage.label(maxima)
  slices = ndimage.find_objects(labeled)
  x,y=[],[]
  for dy,dx in slices:
    x_center = (dx.start + dx.stop - 1)/2
    y_center = (dy.start + dy.stop - 1)/2
    x.append(x_center)
    y.append(y_center)
  return x,y
```

I would like to find a method using a better approach like the derivative in the array or **divide and conquer method**. I will appropriate for a better recommended solution.

Comment: Why does the method you describe (the answer) fail in your case?

Comment: @kezzos it doesn't return the right values..

Comment: Could you explain why the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111711/get-coordinates-of-local-maxima-in-2d-array-above-certain-value "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have tried different threshold values but at the end the indices the code returns do not corresond to the right maximas.

Comment: Are you using a simple definition of a local maximum?  I.e. a point where the value is greater than or equal to the values of its eight neighbors?

Comment: ... or are you trying to avoid lots of "uninteresting" local maxima that can arise in a noisy image?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I would like to obtain local maximas with values greater than 3, meaning I also do not want to obtain neighboring points with more and less the same values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Peak detection in a 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684484/peak-detection-in-a-2d-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [photutils.detection.find_peaks](http://photutils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/photutils.detection.find_peaks.html) function, which is one of the [photutils detection methods](http://photutils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/photutils/detection.html#local-peak-detection).

If you look at the 
[photutils.detection.find_peaks implementation](http://photutils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/photutils/detection/core.html#find_peaks), you'll see that it's using [scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html) to compute a maximum image (by default in a 3x3 box size footprint) and finding the pixels where the original image equals the maximum image.

The rest of the function is mostly for two things that might also be of interest to you:

1. if you pass in a `wcs` object, you can get sky coordinates out, not just pixel coordinates.
2. there's an option to get sub-pixel precision coordinates.

Comment: how should I pass the astronomical coordinate to this function?

Answer (score 4):

So I have this, using skimage adaptive threshold. Hope it helps:

**Original**
[image]

**Code**

```python
from skimage.filters import threshold_adaptive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc, ndimage
import numpy as np

im = misc.imread('\Desktop\MapSNR.jpg')

# Apply a threshold
binary_adaptive = threshold_adaptive(im, block_size=40, offset=-20).astype(np.int)
# Label regions and find center of mass
lbl = ndimage.label(binary_adaptive)
points = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(binary_adaptive, lbl[0], [i+1 for i in range(lbl[1])])

for i in points:
    p = [int(j) for j in i]
    binary_adaptive[i] += 5

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im, interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(binary_adaptive, interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

Changing the parameters of the threshold will have a large effect on where the local maxima will be found, and how many maxima are found.

Comment: Using a Gaussian filter before thresholding may also help to some degree with this method