# Search for all templates using scikit-image

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to follow the tutorial from scikit-image regarding Template Matching (check it [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html)). [image: Themplate matching]

Using just this example, I would like to find all matching coins (maxima) in the image, not only this one which gave the highest score. I was thinking about using:

```
maxima = argrelextrema(result, np.greater)
```

but the problem is that it finds also very small local maxima, which are just a noise. Is there any way to screen numpy array and find the strongest maxima? Thanks!

Comment: You may want `peak_local_max` (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.peak_local_max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been digging and found some solution but unfortunately I am not sure if I know what exactly is done in the script. I have slightly modified script found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111711/get-coordinates-of-local-maxima-in-2d-array-above-certain-value):

```
neighborhood_size = 20   #how many pixels
threshold = 0.01  #threshold of maxima?

data_max = filters.maximum_filter(result, neighborhood_size)
maxima = (result == data_max)
data_min = filters.minimum_filter(result, neighborhood_size)
diff = ((data_max - data_min) > threshold)
maxima[diff == 0] = 0

x_image,y_image = [], []
temp_size = coin.shape[0]

labeled, num_objects = ndimage.label(maxima)
slices = ndimage.find_objects(labeled)
x, y = [], []
for dy,dx in slices:
    x_center = (dx.start + dx.stop - 1)/2
    x.append(x_center)
    y_center = (dy.start + dy.stop - 1)/2
    y.append(y_center)

fig, (raw,found) = plt.subplots(1,2)
raw.imshow(image,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
raw.set_axis_off()
found.imshow(result)
found.autoscale(False)
found.set_axis_off()
plt.plot(x,y, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

and does this:
[image: Found all maxima]

I also realized, that coordinates of found peaks are shifted in comparison to raw image. I think the difference comes from the template size. I will update when I will find out more.

EDIT: with slight code modification I was able also to find places on the input image:

```
x_image_center = (dx.start + dx.stop - 1 + temp_size) / 2
x_image.append(x_image_center)
y_image_center = (dy.start + dy.stop - 1 + temp_size) / 2
y_image.append(y_image_center)
```

[image: Find all patterns in the image with python]

Answer (score 6):

To find all the coins the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html) suggests *"...you should use a proper peak-finding function."*  The easiest of these is probably `peak_local_max` (as suggested in the comments) which is also from skimage, and has a manual page [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.peak_local_max). Using some reasonable numbers in the *args gets the peaks out of the response image.

The second comment about the peaks being displaced is also discussed in the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html)

*"Note that the peaks in the output of match_template correspond to the origin (i.e. top-left corner) of the template."*

One can manually correct for this (by translating the peaks by the side lengths of the template), or you can set the `pad_input` bool to `True` ([source](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.match_template)), which as a by-product means that the peaks in the response function line up with the center of the template at the point of maximal overlap.

Combining these two bits into a script we get something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import match_template
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max # new import!

image = data.coins()
coin = image[170:220, 75:130]

result = match_template(image, coin,pad_input=True) #added the pad_input bool

peaks = peak_local_max(result,min_distance=10,threshold_rel=0.5) # find our peaks

# produce a plot equivalent to the one in the docs
plt.imshow(result)
# highlight matched regions (plural)
plt.plot(peaks[:,1], peaks[:,0], 'o', markeredgecolor='r', markerfacecolor='none', markersize=10)
```

[image: Outputted image of the code snippet above]