# Finding image peaks using ndimage.maximum_filter and skimage.peak_local_max

Tags: python, scikit-image, ndimage

I am trying to find some relative maximums of a given image. I understand that there are two possible methods, the first is using `scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter()` and the second using  `skimage.feature.peak_local_max()`.

In order to compare both methods I have modified an example from skimage [shown here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_peak_local_max.html) in order to compare the peaks found.

```
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage import data, img_as_float

im = img_as_float(data.coins())

# use ndimage to find the coordinates of maximum peaks
image_max = ndi.maximum_filter(im, size=20) == im

j, i = np.where(image_max)
coordinates_2 = np.array(zip(i,j))

# use skimage to find the coordinates of local maxima
coordinates = peak_local_max(im, min_distance=20)

# display results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0].plot(coordinates_2[:, 0], coordinates_2[:, 1], 'r.')
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[0].set_title('Maximum filter')

ax[1].imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1].autoscale(False)
ax[1].plot(coordinates[:, 1], coordinates[:, 0], 'r.')
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[1].set_title('Peak local max')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

This gives the next peaks for each method:
[image]

I understand that the parameter `size` for `maximum_filter` is not equivalent to the `min_distance` from `peak_local_max`, but I'd like to know if there is a method in which both give the same result. Is that possible?

Some related question on stackoverflow are:

[Get coordinates of local maxima in 2D array above certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111711/get-coordinates-of-local-maxima-in-2d-array-above-certain-value)

[Peak detection in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684484/peak-detection-in-a-2d-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you been able to come up with a solution?

I think one step into the direction is simply setting `size=41` in the maximum filter.
This gives me rather similar, though not identical results.
The idea behind that is that `peak_local_max` looks for peaks in a region specified by `2 * min_distance + 1` (Source: [Documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=peak%20local%20max#skimage.feature.peak_local_max)).

Most of the additional peaks identified by `ndi.maximum_filter` are close to the boundary, but there also two additional peaks in the middle of the picture (additional peaks are marked in blue).

[Peaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcYfx.png)

At assume that `peak_local_max` employs some logic to strip boundary peaks and peaks that are close to other peak. Most likely based on the value of the peak.

Comment: You are right! I messed it with the fact that maximum filter uses a square area while peak_loca_max just uses the radius. The other part is that I see on the documentation that you have shared that `peak_local_max` has a parameter called `exclude_border`. By default it is equal to `min_distance` and this removes boundary points. If you edit this i'll accept the answer as the solution. Thanks again