# Find the pixel_maxima in the image and also find its coordinates as well as the peak intensity

Tags: python-3.x, image, scipy

I have this input image and I wan to find pixel maxima and it should look like image2.
I tried contouring but its not working.I also tried scipy pixel_maxima it doesn't gives me result as image2.
here is the code, I have refered this answer ([Get coordinates of local maxima in 2D array above certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111711/get-coordinates-of-local-maxima-in-2d-array-above-certain-value))

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

fname = 'slice-0001-trim.jpg'
neighborhood_size = 10
threshold = 12


data = imageio.imread(fname,as_gray=True)

data_max = filters.maximum_filter(data, neighborhood_size)
maxima = (data == data_max)
data_min = filters.minimum_filter(data, neighborhood_size)
diff = ((data_max - data_min) > threshold)
maxima[diff == 0] = 0

labeled, num_objects = ndimage.label(maxima)
slices = ndimage.find_objects(labeled)
x, y = [], []
for dy,dx in slices:
    x_center = (dx.start + dx.stop - 1)/2
    x.append(x_center)
    y_center = (dy.start + dy.stop - 1)/2    
    y.append(y_center)

plt.imshow(data)
plt.savefig('sample.jpg', bbox_inches = 'tight')

plt.autoscale(False)
plt.plot(x,y, 'ro')
plt.savefig('result.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

[image: Image_1]

I need this image as result

[image: Image_2]

But, I get this image as output
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"not working"*? What results do you get? Does it crash?

Comment: @Mark Setchell It doesn't crash it generates the above output. I have edited in the question