# how can I find and delete overlapped slices of an image from a list?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I have divided an image into objects (slices) using the method kindly contributed by unutbu and Joe Kington at this question: [Rectangular bounding box around blobs in a monochrome image using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525313/rectangular-bounding-box-around-blobs-in-a-monochrome-image-using-python) and have a list of these objects which takes the following form:

```
the_blobs = [(slice(dy.start, dy.stop, None), slice(dx.start, dx.stop, None))]
```

dy.start gives the starting y-pixel value and dy.stop gives the final y-pixel value, and the same deal for dx.

Within the list there are some objects which overlap i.e. one tiny object (a square) is within a larger object such as a circle. When this occurs I want to remove the "enclosed" object from the list (because the circle already has it included) e.g.

**current list**

```
the_blobs = [(slice(100L, 1000L, None), slice(100L, 1000L, None)), 
(slice(150L, 220L, None), slice(150L, 220L, None)), 
(slice(1001L, 2000L, None), slice(1500L, 1700L, None)),
(slice(2001L, 2200L, None), slice(1800L, 1890L, None))]
```

**ideal list (with object removed)**

```
the_blobs = [(slice(100L, 1000L, None), slice(100L, 1000L, None)), 
(slice(1001L, 2000L, None), slice(1500L, 1700L, None)),
(slice(2001L, 2200L, None), slice(1800L, 1890L, None))]
```

I should note that as part of the aforementioned question a suggestion was made to use the following code:

```
data_slices = ndimage.find_objects(coded_paws)
for s in data_slices:
    filled[s] = True
coded_paws, num_paws = ndimage.label(filled)
data_slices = ndimage.find_objects(coded_paws)
```

However this doesn't seem to work 100% of the time, and it really was a contribution slightly beyond the scope of the original question so I'm re-opening this part as a separate, specific question.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

[image: objects as shown in list]

EDIT: Here's an actual image example which doesn't work with the above code

[image]

processing this returns

[image]

and

[image]

Ideally I'd like to remove the last image from the list of slices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can take an O(n^2) approach that checks each blob against all other blobs and determines if it should be removed by checking if `blob1.dx.start > blob2.dx.start and blob1.dy.start > blob2.dy.start and blob1.dx.stop < blob2.dx.stop and blob1.dy.stop < blob2.dy.stop` (if this condition is true, it is ok to remove blob1 from the list).  If your total blob count is pretty low, this should work unless I am missing something.

If you are looking for an optimized solution, it would be helpful to know about how many blobs there are and how common the condition is.