# How to detect license plate in an image with Python and without cvblob?

Tags: python, cvblobslib

I want to detect the presence of a license plate in an image, using Python code.

I got multiple suggestions to use the package cvblob, but I am unable to install cvblob on my Ubuntu system.

What is the best approach to this problem that does not require cvblob?

Comment: you can detect the blobs from an image using pil package 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525313/rectangular-bounding-box-around-blobs-in-a-monochrome-image-using-python

Answer (score 1):

You may use [SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org), it is a wrapper on opencv-python alongwith OCR support which may help you read the license plate text, if its clearly visible. In my experience, it is the most beginner-friendly.