# python library to create a video file from images

Tags: python

I was looking for a light weight python library which would allow me to create a simple video (a slideshow) from a bunch of images. I looked into PyFFMpeg and Pymedia, but they seem really old, and was wondering if anyone knows of any other libraries I could use, (or has had success using PyFFMpeg/Pymedia recently).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go for [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)
And a bit of help from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python)

Comment: OpenCV looks good. Is there anything lighter that you know though? Thanks for your help :)