# How to display an animated gif with Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

I want to open a GIF image from the python console in Linux. Normally when opening a `.png` or `.jpg`, I would do the following:

```
>>> from PIL import Image                                                                                
>>> img = Image.open('test.png')
>>> img.show()
```

But if I do this:

```
>>> from PIL import Image                                                                                
>>> img = Image.open('animation.gif')
>>> img.show()
```

Imagemagick will open but only show the first frame of the gif, not the animation.

Is there a way to show the animation of the GIF in a viewer in Linux?

Comment: What is your operating system? `img.show()` converts temporary image to `BMP` format on Win32 and Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Image.show` dumps the image to a temporary file and then tries to display the file. It calls `ImageShow.Viewer.show_image` (see `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py`):

```
class Viewer:
    def save_image(self, image):
        # save to temporary file, and return filename
        return image._dump(format=self.get_format(image))
    def show_image(self, image, **options):
        # display given image
        return self.show_file(self.save_image(image), **options)
    def show_file(self, file, **options):
        # display given file
        os.system(self.get_command(file, **options))
        return 1
```

AFAIK, the standard PIL [can not save animated GIfs](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2005/12/06/python-imaging-library-pil-and-animated-gifs/)<sup>1</sup>.

The `image._dump` call in `Viewer.save_image` only saves the first frame. So no matter what viewer is subsequently called, you only see a static image.

If you have Imagemagick's `display` program, then you should also have its `animate` program. So if you have the GIF as a file already, then you could use

```
animate /path/to/animated.gif
```

To do so from within Python, you could use the subprocess module (instead of `img.show`):

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['animate', '/path/to/animated.gif'])
proc.communicate()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [According to kostmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376032/190597), there is a script to save animated GIFS with PIL.

---

To show the animation without blocking the main process, use a separate thread to spawn the `animate` command:

```
import subprocess
import threading

def worker():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['animate', '/path/to/animated.gif'])
    proc.communicate()

t = threading.Thread(target = worker)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
# do other stuff in main process
t.join()
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. Anyways I noticed that the python script won't continue until you close the ImageMagick window... Is there any way around this ?

Answer (score 3):

### linux open a gif

I did this with Fedora 17:

```
el@defiant ~ $ sudo yum install gifview
---> Package gifview.x86_64 0:1.67-1.fc17 will be installed

curl http://i.imgur.com/4rBHtSm.gif > mycat.gif

gifview mycat.gif
```

A window comes up and you can step through the frames of the gif.