# python igraph: nodes and edges color according to a number associated to the node

Tags: python, igraph

I'm really new to python and igraph, so the question may be really easy.

I have a network with 128 nodes and an array of 128 numbers, each between 0 and 1. Numbers represent a feature of nodes.

I want two things:

- the color of nodes `i` and `j` has to be the same if `array[i] == array[j]`
- the color of the edge between `i` and `j` has to be given according to this criterion: 
  `if array[i]<=array[j] -> color_edge[ij] = color_node[i]
  else color_edge[ij] = color_node[j]`

I tried many thing, and I think the major problems are:

- `g.vs[i]["color"] = number` doesn't work.I have to insert a string of the type "red" or "HTML notation for color". But how can I associate each number of my array to a string?
- `g.es["color"]` gives a color to all links. However `g.es[i]["color"]` doesn't work (here `g` is my graph and in `g.es[i][".."]`, `i` is the ID of the edge).

About the first question, the only solution I can propose is to assign MANUALLY  a color to each node like

`g.vs[0]["color"] = "red"
.
.
.
g.vs[127]["color"] = "blue"`

then check the condition on `array` and eventually change the color of one of the two nodes (`g.vs[i]["color"] = g.vs[j]["color"]`). But it's a huge loss of time and is not a general way to do that (what if the network has 10^6 nodes?). I was suggested in this [here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2011-04/msg00043.html)

About the second question, I tried to adapt the code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067721/can-i-change-the-colour-of-edges-containing-specific-vertices-in-igraph-python) to my case but the best I obtained was two different colors (and morover I don't understand how they are "the choosen two")

How can I solve this?

P.s. I know I asked two questions, but I think they're very related. However, if necessary, I can edit this post and create a new one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on igrpah mailing list.

To obtain same color of nodes `i` and `j` if `array[i] == array[j]` you can do this:

```
id_gen = UniqueIdGenerator()
color_indices = [id_gen.add(value) for value in array]
palette = ClusterColoringPalette(len(id_gen))
colors = [palette[index] for index in color_indices]
graph.vs["color"] = colors
```

To obtain the color of edges to be determined by the criterion in the question you can do

```
for edge in graph.es:
u, v = edge.tuple
  edge["color"] = colors[u if array[u] <= array[v] else v]
```

The full answer I received from the mailing list is [here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2017-05/msg00042.html).

Comment: @Ludwik can you close the question and mark this answer as the solution to the problem?

Comment: I don't have this kind of power, but additionally answer that consists solely of external links are frowned upon on StackOverflow. The target page can disappear at any moment. You should summarize the solution and keep the link as the source.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary of colors associated with each difference. It's not clear how many colors you need, but assign either a color name "red" or color code "#FFFFFF" to each difference. For example,

```
coldict = {}
coldict[0] = "red"
```

So that when you check the difference array[i] - array[j] = 0, then it assigns red. Do this for all expected differences.

Comment: I need 128 colors. But in the case I have a bigger network, I'd need more. In general, I need one color for each node. This method is very similar to the one I linked and has the problem that I have to assign manually one color fr each difference. Suppose the number of nodes is something like 10^5 or more. You will agree with me that this way is not practicable...