# Is there a simple way to make and save an animation with Pygame?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, save, animated-gif

I made a very simple fractal generator that prints out each step; I want to put it in a presentation I made. The tool with which I'm making the presentation obviously doesn't support pygame, is there any way to save it as a video? Preferably as an animated .gif or the like.

Comment: You could repeatedly save the screen using pygame.image.save(), [documented here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save), and then use the [images2gif.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python) script to turn them into a gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not directly. But you can save a screencast of your program** with one of the many available utilities that do this.

I don't know about Windows or OSX, but if you are on Ubuntu or other gnome-based desktop you can either use the gnome-shell built-in functionality (standard keybinding is `Control+Shift+Alt+R`) or `istanbul` (more info [here](https://live.gnome.org/Istanbul)).

Googling `screencast <your-os-here>` should help if you are not on Ubuntu.

**EDIT:** One you saved the video you can easily convert its format - if you so like - with other utilities. [Here](http://thezestyblogfarmer.blogspot.se/2010/06/turn-your-ogv-movie-section-into.html) is a how-to on how to convert from `ogv` (the standard output for linux screencasting) to animated gif.

Comment: Mint, actually. Pet peeve: assuming that anyone using linux is using ubuntu.

Comment: @GLycan - ...I actually wrote "...or other gnome-based desktop!" (thinking to Fedora, actually, more than Mint...), but I am nevertheless happy you found my answer useful. :) Also forgot to mention (but maybe you know this): gnome-shell is not the standard Ubuntu/Mint desktop, you need to install and login in that mode if you want to use that method. If you are on Fedora, gnome-shell _is_ default. ;)

Answer (score 3):

http://visvis.googlecode.com/hg/vvmovie/images2gif.py -- python package for making animated gifs.

I used it recently for the first time (in conjunction with pygame), so this is not guaranteed to be best practices, but it did work. [Here's the code](http://sjbyrnes.com/astatine.py), [here's the result](http://ataridogdaze.com/science/5fps.gif)

--

UPDATE: Over time I've decided that images2gif.py is mediocre (produces unnecessarily large files) and unreliable (sometimes randomly fails to load and run). My new preference is to call imagemagick using subprocess. [Example code here.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SquareWaveFourierArrows.gif#Source_code) [Here is a shorter example in Windows (from the comments).](http://pastebin.com/JJ6ZuXdz)

Comment: Nice, I did not know about it! +1 for me! :)

Comment: After having looked around a while for a way to generate animated GIFs using Python, I've now come to agree that your suggested method using subprocess and ImageMagick is the best approach. I threw together a more minimal example here: http://pastebin.com/JJ6ZuXdz