# PIL - generated picture as a GIF animations in django

Tags: python, django, animation, python-imaging-library, gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically generate video or animated GIF in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python)

My idea is very simple:  PIL script on a Django-powered website generates a picture and this picture is then animated as a GIF animation. I know how to do the first part - generate image file with PIL, but I have no idea how to use this file to animate it.
I expect that soultion is very simple, but I am a Django - beginner.
Thanks!