# How can I make a GIf like image using python

Tags: image, python-3.x, slideshow, animated-gif, multimedia

all I am trying to make a program to help deaf people communicate with the average person For a few signs you need to have a moving image! What my goal is to have a gif like an image or a slide show that will go from one image to the next making it like a moving image.
The modules I am currently using are:

- easygui
- random
- time
- sys
- os
- curses
- locale

I have never done anything with images using python. I am using a mac but I need anything else I might need to add to be multi-platform. I am hoping someone has more experiences with python than I do. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190).

You may also want to change your approach to using [pydown](https://github.com/isnowfy/pydown), which generates slides as HTML5 + javascript from simple markdown text and stores everything as a self-contained package. End-users only need a browser to view the result. You may add your own javascript to flip slides after a timeout...

Comment: I spent 1 hours googling this and that never came up