# How to create a multiple frame .tif image using Python PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, tiff

How would I go about creating a new image, using python PIL, which has multiple frames in it.

```
new_Image = Image.new("I;16", (num_pixels,num_rows))

for frame in range((len(final_rows)/num_rows)):
    pixels = new_Image.load()

    for row in range(num_rows):
        row_pixel = final_rows[row].getPixels()
        for pixel in range(num_pixels):
            pixels[pixel,row] = row_pixel[pixel]
    print frame
    new_Image.seek(frame)
```

I tried using the above code but it gives me a EOFError. The code gets the number of frames by dividing the total number of rows that I have by the number of rows per frame. It then uses the data as pixel data. I was trying to seek a new frame but I guess it hasn't been created. How do I create these frames?

Edit: I would like a .tif file format

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python/12092932#12092932

Comment: @Paul No I haven't tried that. I don't really want to create a Movie or Gif. The file format that I want is .tif.

Answer (score 1):

`new_Image` is what you have loaded, i.e. **read** - if it doesn't have more than one frame you can not move on the the next.

For the moment PIL does not have support for creating Multi-Frame GIFs so you would need to switch to [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1) which does - there is some sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/master/Scripts/gifmaker.py).

### Update

Took the time to investigate further and found a bug fixed version of `images2gif` so what **I** did was to use `pip install images2gif` and then downloaded the bug fixed version from [here](https://github.com/rec/echomesh/blob/master/code/python/external/images2gif.py) and overwrote the one installed by `pip` but you could just download that bug fix version and put it in the same directory as your development file.

I then created a CreateGif.py file:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import glob
from PIL import Image
from images2gif import writeGif

DELAY=0.75  # How long between frames
FRAMES = [] # Empty list of frames
FIRST_SIZE = None # I am going to say that the first file is the right size
OUT_NAME = "test.gif" # Name to save to
filelist = glob.glob("*.jpg") # For this test I am just using the images in the current directory in the order they are

for fn in filelist:  # For each name in the list
    img = Image.open(fn) # Read the image
    if FIRST_SIZE is None:  # Don't have a size
        FIRST_SIZE = img.size  # So use this one
    if img.size == FIRST_SIZE: # Check the current image size if it is OK we can use it
        print ("Adding:", fn)  # Show some progress
        FRAMES.append(img)   # Add it to our frames list
    else:
        print ("Discard:", fn, img.size, "<>", FIRST_SIZE) # You could resize and append here!

print("Writing", len(FRAMES), "frames to", OUT_NAME)
writeGif(OUT_NAME, FRAMES, duration=DELAY, dither=0)
print("Done")
```

Running this in **my** test directory resulted in:

```
F:\Uploads>python CreateGif.py
Adding: Hidden.jpg
Adding: NewJar.jpg
Adding: P1000063.JPG
Adding: P1000065.JPG
Adding: P1000089.JPG
Discard: WiFi_Virgin.jpg (370, 370) <> (800, 600)
Writing 5 frames to test.gif
Done
```

And produced: [image]

### And Now For TiFF files

First I installed tiffile, `pip install -U tiffile`, *I already had numpy installed*, then:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import glob
from PIL import Image
import tifffile
import numpy

def PIL2array(img):
    """ Convert a PIL/Pillow image to a numpy array """
    return numpy.array(img.getdata(),
        numpy.uint8).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], 3)
FRAMES = [] # Empty list of frames
FIRST_SIZE = None # I am going to say that the first file is the right size
OUT_NAME = "test.tiff" # Name to save to
filelist = glob.glob("*.jpg") # For this test I am just using the images in the current directory in the order they are
# Get the images into an array
for fn in filelist:  # For each name in the list
    img = Image.open(fn) # Read the image
    if FIRST_SIZE is None:  # Don't have a size
        FIRST_SIZE = img.size  # So use this one
    if img.size == FIRST_SIZE: # Check the current image size if it is OK we can use it
        print ("Adding:", fn)  # Show some progress
        FRAMES.append(img)   # Add it to our frames list
    else:
        print ("Discard:", fn, img.size, "<>", FIRST_SIZE) # You could resize and append here!

print("Writing", len(FRAMES), "frames to", OUT_NAME)
with tifffile.TiffWriter(OUT_NAME) as tiff:
    for img in FRAMES:
        tiff.save(PIL2array(img),  compress=6)
print("Done")
```

Which produced a nice tiff file, *but unfortunately the SO viewer does not display multi-page tiff files that windows at least thinks is acceptable as can be seen below.*
[image]

Comment: new image is what I created using  `new_Image = Image.new("I;16", (num_pixels,num_rows))`. That sample code doesn't seem to create a new image only access an existing one `im = Image.open(infile)`.

Comment: You are expected to supply a set of images as input to the example.  Image.new is NOT what is in your sample code BTW.

Comment: Sorry it was in the line above

Comment: As gifmaker has been merged in pillow, the second URL is no longer relevant :p (and I'm still struggling to create one multi-framed image)

Comment: @RomualdBrunet - Some worked examples for both gif and tiff added.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a PIL image of the first frame, then save that and pass the other frame images in a list to the `append_images` parameter and save them all. It works with `webp`, `gif`, and `tiff` formats, though `tiff` appears to ignore the duration and loop parameters:

```
im1.save(save_to, format="tiff", append_images=[im2], save_all=True, duration=500, loop=0)
```

See also the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving-sequences).