# Saving a multipage tiff using PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff

A multipage tiff can be saved to a file using PIL: `im.save(filepath, save_all=True)`. My question is how to convert a list of numpy arrays to the im object recognised by PIL. `im = PIL.Image.fromarray()` doesn't accept a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality was just added to Pillow v.4.1.0.dev0 
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/2406

There are also some other solutions with other libs. E.g. with tifffile [How to create a multiple frame image using Python PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540119/how-to-create-a-multiple-frame-image-using-python-pil)

Comment: Some other solutions:

[Through gif](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2401#issuecomment-280095355).


[With tiffimageplugin](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2191#issuecomment-274285059).