Write a lossless-compressed image with multiple layers
How to save an image, losslessly compressed, with multiple layers (like with Photoshop PSD but rather an open format), with OpenCV cv2 or PIL/Pillow ?
Note: Is seems that TIFF format can do this (see this answer), but as I remember TIFF have lower compression ratio than PNG.
Pseudo code:
import cv2
cv2.imwrite('test.tiff', layer1, layer2, layer3)


You will have to use TIFF with LZW or ZIP compression or GIF to get multiple layers, but these are usually just pages or frames not true layers.  TIFF can save layers but I do not know software other that Photoshop and perhaps GIMP that can actually do true layers.

@fmw42 Pages or frames could be ok. How to save multiple pages or frames into a TIFF with Python built-in modules (or, maybe, cv2)?

Check PIL also see https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce which claims that cv2.imwrite can write multiple image to a tiff.  Also see https://products.aspose.com/words/python-net/merge/tiff/

Use Python subprocess to call Imagemagick, which can easily write multiple pages to a TIFF.

@fmw42 Thanks! Can you post a sample code with PIL or cv2.imwrite? It would be great!

Sorry, I have never done that. I just searched Google for answers and posted those. Why don't you try and post your code attempt and any error messages. Others might then be able to help you further

See also https://github.com/mpascucci/multipagetiff

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600205/saving-a-multipage-tiff-using-pil

See also https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2191

See also imageio at https://www.scivision.dev/writing-multipage-tiff-with-python/

See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377120/create-one-tiff-from-several-images

See https://docs.opencv.org/4.10.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga325154ef5814747ec6c3c3d97be69b49

The most comprehensive support for reading/writing TIFFs in Python is almost certainly tifffile.
If you want lossless compression, try LZW and ZIP.

Thank you @MarkSetchell! Out of curiosity, can TIFF with LZW or ZIP match the by-default PNG compression ratio and compression speed?

@Basj. Why don't you just do a test of both?  Seems simple enough.  My experience is that compressed TIFF is about the same size as PNG.

My feeling is that it depends heavily on the image content. The row-wise filtering in PNG is very effective for some content types and LZW will have difficulty matching that if your subject matter is such that each row is heavily correlated with the preceding row. As Fred says, try it.
