# a movie created by several pictures of Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-2.7

As we know, Python Turtle can save its Turtle Screen to a picture of ".eps" format. But is it possible to create a whole movie using pictures of this type? If not, is it possible to create movie on Python other way without downloading any extra software? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in a couple ways.

If you absolutely must have a real movie format (like mpeg), you'll have to use `pymedia`. [Here's an example script](http://pymedia.org/tut/src/make_video.py.html) which saves a pygame image to a movie sequence.

If instead you can accept a `.gif` sequence, `PIL` can read `eps` file format images (among many others), and can make .gif's using a handy script [explained in an unaccepted SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376032/829811) by [kostmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105137/kostmo).