# Creating a gif in python using ImageMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, animated-gif

I am trying to create a gif using python either through the GraphicsMagick module or using os.system commands with the ImageMagick.exe.  The most relevant question I have found here was this question about 6 years ago.

[Similar Question 6 years old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python)

URL for imagemagick download

file:///C:/Program%20Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/www/binary-releases.html#windows

[GraphicsMagick Download](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pgmagick)

Below is my code (not working).  I am currently trying the ImageMagick route as the above question stated that this was more pythonic.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
from pgmagick import Image, ImageList, Geometry, Color 
import os, sys
import glob

#dataDir = sys.argv[1]
#outDir  = sys.argv[2]

dataDir = 'C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\a'

os.chdir(dataDir)
fileList = glob.glob(dataDir + '\*.jpg')
fileList.sort()

os.system('convert fileList -delay 20 -loop 0 *jpg animated.gif')
```

I get an invalid syntax error on the last line of my code.

Comment: Surround the argument in quotes (`os.system('convert...gif')`).

Comment: Thanks.  That is one mistake down.  I still have the overall problem of not fully understanding the imagemagick commands.  I now have an invalid parameter error.

Comment: I think when [the guy in that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python#comment34815046_753832) said to use `convert -delay 20 -loop 0 *jpg animated.gif`, he meant, just paste it straight into the command line and don't bother using Python at all. That would save you a lot of time in wrestling with `system` etc.

Comment: In any case, this reminds me of [my own experiments in executing ImageMagick from Python](http://pastebin.com/Vw3KuUj0). Maybe you'll find some useful insights in there. For example, I had better luck with `subprocess.call` than with `os.system`. Still not sure why though.

Comment: I opened a command window in the directory with the jpg files and used that exact command.  I still get an invalid parameter error.

Comment: Thanks.  I will get that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that sees this in the future when trying to make a gif with imagemagick on a windows machine, this is the solution that I figured out.  I don't know if this is the most efficient way in terms of memory, but it works.

```
import os, sys

dataDir = 'fullpath of directory with images'
os.chdir(dataDir)


os.system('SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion')
#This is the path of the imagemagick installation convert command.  
#The invalid parameter I was  getting was because the computer was trying to 
#use a different convert command.  This code sets convert as a different
#variable and then calls that new variable as the convert command.  
os.system('SET IMCONV="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\Convert"')
os.system('%IMCONV% *.jpg animated.gif')
```

Some changes I made to simplify the solution.  Instead of making a file list as I did in my question, I just stuck all the images in a directory, and then called the command to convert these images to a gif. This is the simplest solution that I have come across.