# RGBA, palette and dither issues with creating animated gif using image2gif.py python

Tags: animation, gif, palette

I have successfully created an animated gif but there are 2 problems - the resulting animated gif is gray scale and dithered. I have used variants on Robert King's code snippet found here

[Programmatically generate video or animated GIF in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python)

The King code snippet uses writeGif from image2gif.py with the following modifications: (i) the lines accessing "palette" (around line 97  in my version of image2gif.py), as per stackoverflow Q&A's

```
        #palette = getheader(im)[1]
        palette = im.palette.getdata()[1]
```

(ii) I ALSO had to add some code to account for the type of image that I have, the shape is of the image is 4 which I interpret as RGBA and I added lines 3 and 4 to writeGif (around line 186 in my image2gif.py)

1            if len(im.shape)==3 and im.shape[2]==3:

2                im = Image.fromarray(im,'RGB').convert('P',dither=dither)

3            elif len(im.shape)==3 and im.shape[2]==4:

4                im = Image.fromarray(im,'RGBA').convert('P',dither=dither)

5            elif len(im.shape)==2:

6                im = Image.fromarray(im,'L').convert('P',dither=dither)

How do I get color correct?.  I think I am not accessing and writing the palette properly.  I don't see any discussion of this.

NOTE: I can create an animated gif with these png files using GifConstructionKit (windows) but I have thousands of animated gifs to create and would like a programmatic solution.  (I don't have ffmpeg nor installed openCV, yet.)

paulj03

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my own problem. I finally understood the messages about imagemagick and convert.exe.  I downloaded and installed it then I wrote a script to execute convert.exe using the os.system function.

```
import os
cmd = 'cd <directory with images>'
cmd2 = 'convert *.png movie.gif'
os.system(cmd)
os.system(cmd2)
```

I actually write everything to a bat file and then run from a cmd windows (Windows machine).  It seems much much faster than from Python console.