# Custom Frame Duration for Animated Gif in Python ImageIO

Tags: python, image, animation

I've been playing around with animated gifs in Python, where the frames will be produced by a Raspberry Pi Camera located in a greenhouse. I have used the recommended imageio code from [Almar's answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943809/859141) with success to create simple gifs.

However, I'm now trying to slow down the frame duration but looking at the [documentation for imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) and cannot find any references for mimsave but do see [mimwrite](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userapi.html#imageio.mimwrite), which should take four args. I've looked at the [additional gif documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_gif.html#gif) and can see that there is a duration argument.

Currently, my code looks like:

```
exportname = "output.gif"
kargs = { 'duration': 5 }
imageio.mimsave(exportname, frames, 'GIF', kargs)
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "makegif.py", line 23, in <module>
imageio.mimsave(exportname, frames, 'GIF', kargs)
TypeError: mimwrite() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

where frames is a list of imageio.imread objects.  Why is this?

UPDATED TO SHOW FULL ANSWER:
This is an example showing how to created animated gifs with imageio using kwargs to change the frame duration.

```
import imageio
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print("Not enough args - add the full path")

indir = sys.argv[1]

frames = []

# Load each file into a list
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
  for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        print(filename)
        frames.append(imageio.imread(indir + "/" + filename))


# Save them as frames into a gif 
exportname = "output.gif"
kargs = { 'duration': 5 }
imageio.mimsave(exportname, frames, 'GIF', **kargs)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mimsave` does not accept 4 *positional* arguments. Anything beyond the 3rd argument must be provided as a *keyword argument*. In other words, you have to unpack `kargs` like so:

```
imageio.mimsave(exportname, frames, 'GIF', **kargs)
```

Answer (score 28):

Or you could just call it like that:

```
imageio.mimsave(exportname, frames, format='GIF', duration=5)
```

Comment: In imageio version '2.5.0', instead of duration we have to give the FPS directly as 'fps' argument. `imageio.imsave(exportname, frames, format='GIF', fps=30`)

Answer (score 7):

I've found this to be the simplest and most robust solution

```
import imageio
import os

path = '/path/to/script/and/frames'
image_folder = os.fsencode(path)

filenames = []

for file in os.listdir(image_folder):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith( ('.jpeg', '.png', '.gif') ):
        filenames.append(filename)

filenames.sort() # this iteration technique has no built in order, so sort the frames

images = list(map(lambda filename: imageio.imread(filename), filenames))
```

**and then this last line of the script is the one you are looking for**

```
imageio.mimsave(os.path.join('my_very_own_gif.gif'), images, duration = 0.04) # modify the frame duration as needed
```