# making gif from images using imageio in python

Tags: python, animated-gif, python-imageio

I have tried reading a lot of examples online and found `imageio` is the perfect package for it. [Also found examples written in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python).

I have just followed the example as shown and tried the following

```
import imageio as io
import os
file_names = sorted((fn for fn in os.listdir('.') if fn.startswith('surface')))
#making animation
with io.get_writer('surface.gif', mode='I', duration=0.5) as writer:
    for filename in file_names:
        image = io.imread(filename)
        writer.append_data(image)
writer.close()
```

and another example.

```
images = []
for filename in file_names:
    images.append(io.imread(filename))
io.mimsave('surface1.gif', images, duration = 0.5)
```

both of these do not work. And basically i only see the first frame from the gif and a blink and finish. The duration is set 0.5secs, so it should work fine. I might have been missing out something here.

Comment: Both approaches work on Python 2.7.1 and [´imageio´ 2.1.2](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/imageio) ([1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By7vRQt-oAVdZXhtbU1yNUlQN0E) [2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By7vRQt-oAVdaUhhbmxVRnotT1U)), using several .png images. Are you sure all the images you want to use are being selected? Check the `file_names` list to see if they are all there.

Comment: I have tried the first approach. it works for about 758 .png files. But I have around 3000 .png files and the files after 758 are not appended in the .gif file. Is there any reason for that? I know the file_names array has those files. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650649/why-is-my-gif-missing-png-files-after-250-iterations for more on my question. Thanks!!

Comment: Check out https://www.quora.com/How-long-can-a-GIF-animate

Comment: duration should be set in mili seconds and not seconds.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import os
import imageio

png_dir = '../animation/png'
images = []
for file_name in sorted(os.listdir(png_dir)):
    if file_name.endswith('.png'):
        file_path = os.path.join(png_dir, file_name)
        images.append(imageio.imread(file_path))

# Make it pause at the end so that the viewers can ponder
for _ in range(10):
    images.append(imageio.imread(file_path))

imageio.mimsave('../animation/gif/movie.gif', images)
```

Comment: This is the most easy and elegant solution I've found so far. One suggestion, add the sorted function before the list_dir function:
`sorted(os.listdir(png_dir))`

Comment: I'm trying this solution, but the issue here is image transparency, while creating GIF some image color changed

Comment: @Kunal you need to school yourself on getting a consistent color pallet across each gif before you combine them.

Comment: @DaveBabbitt I am using this solution but facing color change issue in the image. Please use PIL but only one thing remember 1 second==100 mili second.

Comment: How can we slow down the gif?

Comment: `imageio.mimsave` has a `duration=` parameter in seconds

Answer (score 29):

in case anyone needs it,
for python 3.6.8, it needed `fps`

```py
imageio.mimsave('/path/file.gif',images,fps=55)
```

Comment: it does not support fps anymore, what version of imageio is this so that i can use it?

Comment: 24/01/24: it works again exactly as provided here