# Python Bokeh: How do I keep the y-axis tick marks stable?

Tags: python, bokeh

Here I've taken some [gapminder.org data](http://www.gapminder.org/data/) and looped through the years to create a series of charts (which I [converted to an animated gif in imageio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228209/making-gif-from-images-using-imageio-in-python/45258744#45258744)) by modifying the [Making Interactive Visualizations with Bokeh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/georgetown-analytics/XBUS-506-01.Visual_Analytics/master/bokeh/gapminder.ipynb) notebook.

[image: 4.5 MB animated gif produced by bokeh and imageio in 300 seconds and uploaded to imgur]

The problem is that when the Middle Eastern countries float to the top in the 1970s, the y-axis tick marks (and the legend) gets perturbed. I'm keeping as many things as possible out of the year loop when I build the plots, so my y-axis code looks like this:

```
# Personal income (GDP per capita)
y_low = int(math.floor(income_df.min().min()))
y_high = int(math.ceil(income_df.max().max()))
y_data_range = DataRange1d(y_low-0.5*y_low, 1000000*y_high)

# ...

for year in columns_list:

        # ...

        # Build the plot
        plot = Plot(

            # Children per woman (total fertility)
            x_range=x_data_range,

            # Personal income (GDP per capita)
            y_range=y_data_range,
            y_scale=LogScale(),

            plot_width=800,
            plot_height=400,
            outline_line_color=None,
            toolbar_location=None, 
            min_border=20,
        )

        # Build the axes
        xaxis = LinearAxis(ticker=SingleIntervalTicker(interval=x_interval), 
                           axis_label="Children per woman (total fertility)", 
                           **AXIS_FORMATS)
        yaxis = LogAxis(ticker=LogTicker(), 
                        axis_label="Personal income (GDP per capita)",
                        **AXIS_FORMATS)
        plot.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')
        plot.add_layout(yaxis, 'left')
```

As you can see, I've bumped up the data range by a factor of 10^6 with no effect. Is there some parameter I need to add to keep my y-axis tick marks (and legend) stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `DataRange1d`, that's what is actually doing the "auto-ranging". If you know the full range that you want to always show up front use a `Range1d`:

```
Plot(y_range=Range1d(low, high), ...)
```

or more for convenience this will also work:

```
Plot(y_range=(low, high), ...)
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks.