# How to record an interactive plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, video, recording

1.This becomes the interactive plot I am referring to. You will need to open the figure that appears at the bottom of the screen (if it does not display automatically) immediately after you start the program, in order to see the "animation". My question is: how do I record all of the updates in this interactive plot as a video? I do not want to record the screen. I also do not want to replace my current code **fully** with an animation object. Is there any way to create a video recording this interactive plot by **supplementing** the interactive plotting code rather than **fully replacing** it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion() 
plt.figure()

for i in range(1000):
    plt.axis((0,10,0,100))
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i],'ro')
    plt.pause(.1)
    plt.cla()

plt.clf()
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to ask here if you exclude the available options beforehands.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python) is how to create an animated gif. But of course using `FuncAnimation` is much easier.

Comment: Why is this tagged simulation?  In what way does that impact your question about recording the results?

Comment: I updated the question so that it is more clear.