# How to add matplotlib output to a video

Tags: python, matplotlib, video-processing

I'm trying to create a video with annotation (currently) formed from matplotlib, with the original video on the left and a FFT of some parameters on the right.

The only way I've gotten it to work is by saving a .png file for each frame, which seems tedious.  I was hoping someone could point out the 'correct' method.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import scipy.fftpack
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip

vid = VideoFileClip('VID.mp4')
aud = AudioFileClip('VID.mp4')
out  = cv2.VideoWriter('1234.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), vid.fps, (vid.w*2, vid.h))
audIndex = 0
vidIndex = 0
numberOfSamples = 600
sampleRate = 800;
T = 1.0 / sampleRate;
x = np.linspace(0.0, numberOfSamples*T, numberOfSamples)

for frame in vid.iter_frames():

    # Put the recorded movie on the left side of the video frame
    frame2 = np.zeros((frame.shape[0], 2*frame.shape[1], 3)).astype('uint8')
    frame2[:720, :1280,:] = frame


    # Put, say, a graph of the FFT on the right side of the video frame
    y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
    yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
    xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), numberOfSamples/2)
    fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
    ax.plot(xf, 2.0/numberOfSamples * np.abs(yf[:numberOfSamples//2]))
    matFigureForThisFrame = ????????

    # Put the FFT graph on the left side of this video frame
    frame2[720:, 1280:, :] = matFigureForThisFrame

    out.write(frame2)
    vidIndex = vidIndex+1;

out.release()
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to take the path of writing to a video file directly, but I wouldn't recommend it (see [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/) why). Writing to video file is more complicated than just changing the frames, you need to need to get the right coders and other painful issues. Personally, I would settle. Some options:

1) Generate the pngs, and afterwards concatenating them to a video file using `ffmpeg`

2) Save each frame to a buffer, and generate `.gif` file afterwards, directly in `python` (so you don't have to run multiple things). See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python) on how to do that.