# imageio - ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imageio

I have a series of SVG images (generated from `matplotlib`) and I want to combine them into a GIF image.

Since I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943809/10811334), I tried `imageio`, but it raised `ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'` at `imread(str(i)+'.svg')` part. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is a vector format, and is not supported by imageio: type `imageio.help()` to display all supported formats.

You'll need to use an svg to bitmap converter first (rasterize the image, this will let you choose the image's quality).
Or even better, look if there's a native way to make SVG animations (google finds a few tutorials on this subject).