# Why can't I make a GIF from PIL.Image.Image files but can with PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make GIF from multiple image files, following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python).

Kris's answer works perfectly when I open a physical file from a directory using `Image.open()` and then append the list to make a GIF.

```py
imgs = [Image.open(f) for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd())]
imgs[0].save('{}.gif'.format(img_filename),
                              format='GIF',
                              append_images=imgs[1:],
                              save_all=True,
                              duration=args.duration,
                              loop=0)
```

This works fine and the output GIF is infact animated. I noticed that the list `glitched_imgs` consists of `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` objects in this case.

However whenever I try to use an `Image` object returned from a function, The GIF produced is completely static.

```py
imgs = [get_randomized_image() for _ in range(args.frames)]
imgs[0].save('{}.gif'.format(img_filename),
                              format='GIF',
                              append_images=imgs[1:],
                              save_all=True,
                              duration=args.duration,
                              loop=0)
```

Where `get_randomized_image()` returns a randomized `Image` object, specifically from a `numpy` array.

```py
    # Inside `get_glitched_image()`
    return Image.fromarray(outputarr, img_mode)
```

I want to directly make a GIF with a list of objects returned from this function, how can I achieve this?

Note: The files I open in the first (working) method, are the files I saved prior using `get_randomized_images()` so I can assure you they are exactly the same.

Comment: Did you check how many images are in your randomised list? And print them to see their sizes and modes to ensure they match?

Comment: Maybe ensure they are all RGBA by changing to `return Image.fromarray(...).convert('RGBA')`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I forgot to mention, so I added an edit. The  images I used in the first (working) method were created by using `.save()` on the returned `Image` object from the same function - `get_randomized_images()`. 


I just open those same files in the first (working) method and directly use the `Image` object in the second. So in both methods, the data is exactly the same format

Comment: @MarkSetchell Also yes, the length of the list is the same (23 for this specific use case) in both methods

Comment: If you open a PNG file, convert it to a Numpy array and then convert back to PIL Image and save, you will not necessarily get a similar file.

Comment: I see, is there perhaps a way to turn `Image` into `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` without having to save and reopen?